# matplotlib different custom styles for hist plot scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have managed to get custom styles working by placing foobar.mplstyle into ~/.config/matplotlib/stylelib/foobar.mplstyle

Now I would like to have different grid options for different plots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
plt.style.use('foobar')
plt.plot([random.random() for _ in range(50)])
plt.show()

plt.hist([random.random() for _ in range(50)])
plt.show()
```

In the first case I would like to have complete grid.

In the histogram case I would like to have just horizontal gridlines

Is that possible or I would have to create 2 styles
fooplot.mplstyle
foohist.mplstyle

and do

```
with style.use('fooplot'):
   plt.plot([random.random() for _ in range(50)])
   plt.show() 

with style.use('foohist'):
    plt.hist([random.random() for _ in range(50)])
    plt.show()
```

Also what is the exact settings I put into my foobar.mplstyle file for either horizontal or vertical gridlines?
Neither

```
grid.axis : x
```

nor

```
grid.axis : y
```

nor

```
grid.axis : both
```

seems to work (throwing error)

EDIT: code of my mplstyle file. This makes classic horizontal+vertical grid and works fine.

```
### LINES
lines.linewidth   : 1.0     # line width in points
lines.linestyle   : -       # solid line
lines.antialiased : True         # render lines in antialised (no jaggies)

### TEXT
text.color          : black

### AXES
axes.hold           : True    
axes.facecolor      : white
axes.edgecolor      : EEE2CB   # axes edge color
axes.linewidth      : 1.0     # edge linewidth
axes.grid           : True   # display grid or not
axes.titlesize      : large   # fontsize of the axes title
axes.labelsize      : medium  # fontsize of the x any y labels
axes.labelweight    : normal  # weight of the x and y labels
axes.labelcolor     : k
axes.axisbelow      : False   # whether axis gridlines and ticks are below
                               # the axes elements (lines, text, etc)

axes.formatter.use_locale : True # When True, format tick labels
                                   # according to the user's locale.
                                   # For example, use ',' as a decimal
                                   # separator in the fr_FR locale.
axes.color_cycle : 95c11f, 1f94d2, e5004b, 28b195, black  # color cycle for plot lines

### TICKS
xtick.color          : k      # color of the tick labels
ytick.color          : k
xtick.major.size : 0 
xtick.minor.size : 0 
ytick.major.size : 0 
ytick.minor.size : 0 


### GRIDS
grid.linestyle   :   -       # dotted
grid.linewidth   :   2     # in points
grid.alpha       :   0.5     # transparency, between 0.0 and 1.0
grid.color        : eee2cb


### Legend
legend.frameon       : False   # whether or not to draw a frame around legend
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your mplstyle file?

Comment: Now I am thinking whether it wouldnt be easier to define a custom function and set required parameters in the function?